# VLC plays every other track silently and causes bizarre input problems?

Tags: keyboard, audio-playback, input-device, mouse, vlc

I'm running a new Pi4 with Buster (desktop with recommended software)

When I play media files off my old Mac hard drive, VLC works wonderfully for the first file.  However, when I give it a whole folder to play, only the first file plays normally.  After that first file, it seems to alternate whether the playback works or not.  More troublingly, my inputs (both keyboard and mouse) are totally frozen for a while (between 30 seconds and until the next track starts) after the second track fails to play—I have no explanation for this, but it is a repeatable pattern.

#### Mouse

The cursor doesn't immediately stop responding, but it gets slow and unreliable.  Eventually, it stops moving entirely.  However, only the display of the cursor is frozen in place: when I move the mouse with the frozen cursor, I can click elsewhere and see the cursor change to match what I should be hovering over (pointer to text caret, for example).

#### Keyboard

The keyboard is initially frozen.  However, it then does a rapid-fire repeat of a key or two I pressed while it was frozen and then works normally.

### Questions

1. What is causing this mess?  I heard from a friend that their VLC doesn't like playing the next file but theirs doesn't seem as haunted as mine.
2. What console command(s) can I use to make the cursor's display move again?

---

As an aside, I can't seem to get my Pi to connect to my home wi-fi at all but it reliably connects to my phone's hotspot (also wi-fi).  I doubt this is related, but there could be some bizarre root cause.

Comment: Is your Wi-Fi country set correctly?

Comment: @CoderMike I'm in the US and it's set to US.  Do you know how I can get it to tell me what went wrong instead of a useless "failed to connect to network" pop-up?  That would be helpful in solving this problem.